# How to guarantee or detect the data integrity in flink?

Tags: etl, apache-flink

Background:
We use flink to consume data from kafka and write to HDFS in hour partitions. And We don't set the watermarks because we want all the record consumed.
so we get directories like

```
/data/app1/day=2019-01-01/hour=01/
/data/app1/day=2019-01-01/hour=02/
...
/data/app1/day=2019-01-01/hour=23/
```

Other jobs need our data as input, so the data are not intact if something some late data may even arrive several hours later, which leads to incorrect result for downstream jobs.

So my question is how to guarantee or detect the data integrity in flink?

Comment: From what you wrote I would expect you want to have the data bucketed in event-time right?

Comment: I have had the data bucketed. I want to know whether all the data in each buckets are ready or not.

Comment: Could you please extend the question: how would you decide if a given bucket is complete? If you want to handle arbitrarily late events, doesn't that mean that you can never perform downstream processes as the data is potentially never complete?

Comment: Exactly what @ArvidHeise said: If you rely on processing time your bucket will be closed as soon as the hour passed (this bucket will be immutable from that time on). If you rely on event-time you have to define a threshold on when late-events should be droped (or handled in another way)

Comment: @ArvidHeise I can't decide when is complete and that is excatly my question. Exactly what you said, downstream processes should not perform when  the data is not complete. But I have to mention that the data will late 30mins at most in normal situation.

Comment: @TobiSH We rely on event-time and didn't want to drop late data because we rarely have late data. We are finding a way to prevent downstream processes from running with incomplete data, which caused by a error flink task.

Comment: How would you know that your data is incomplete?

Comment: If you really need to process arbitrary late events, I'd drop S3 as an intermediate storage and use Kafka or similar system to transfer data from Flink to downstream processes.